# SparkConf not found running spark neo4j connector example

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j

I execute the spark neo4j example code like so:

```
spark-shell --conf spark.neo4j.bolt.password=TestNeo4j --packages neo4j-contrib:neo4j-spark-connector:1.0.0-RC1,graphframes:graphframes:0.1.0-spark1.6 -i neo4jspark.scala
```

My Scalafile:

```
import org.neo4j.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf



val conf = new SparkConf.setMaster("local").setAppName("neo4jspark")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)   
val neo = Neo4j(sc)



val rdd = neo.cypher("MATCH (p:POINT) RETURN p").loadRowRdd
rdd.count
```

The error:

```
Loading neo4jspark.scala...
import org.neo4j.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
<console>:38: error: not found: value SparkConf
       val conf = new SparkConf.setMaster("local").setAppName("neo4jspark")
                      ^
<console>:38: error: not found: value conf
       val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
                                 ^
<console>:39: error: not found: value Neo4j
       val neo = Neo4j(sc)
                 ^
<console>:38: error: not found: value neo
       val rdd = neo.cypher("MATCH (p:POINT) RETURN p").loadRowRdd
                 ^
<console>:39: error: object count is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd
       rdd.count
           ^
```

I am importing the SparkConf, no idea whay it says there is no value for that, am I missing something (simple I hope)??

EDIT: This seems to be a version error:

I ran it with this start up:

```
spark-shell --conf spark.neo4j.bolt.password=TestNeo4j --packages neo4j-contrib:neo4j-spark-connector:2.0.0-M2,graphframes:graphframes:0.2.0-spark2.0-s_2.11 -i neo4jspark.scala
```

Still get the conf error but it does run.  I just need to now figure out why anything i do with the returned RDD breaks :D This is on mac, just tested same versions of everything on my windows and it breaks like it showed her mostly because it couldn't get the import.org.neo4j.spark._  here is the error:

```
<console>:23: error: object neo4j is not a member of package org
       import org.neo4j.spark._
                  ^
```

No idea what is different about windows than the mac I am deving on :/